# Using “Video 90” spray to clean up a cell phone motherboard

Tags: cellphone, motherboard, cleaning

Can I use Video 90 Spray with electronic motherboards, like smartphones?

My cell phone was dropped in water while the battery was out, now I have dried it out using rice and instant oat!

Before, plugging it back on, I want to use a spray cleaner on it.

Video 90 is generally available in my local market, please let know if you think this could work for electronic devices as well.

Video 90 description:

http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/318263.pdf

http://www.connector.nl/image/imagedir/kontakt_chemie/TechnicalManual_CatalogKontaktChemie2015English.pdf

Comment: Whatever you use, be careful not to get any on/in the LCD. I wasn't and now my screen is permanently blotchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good with no residue depends entirely on number of rinses and dust level. Beware Apple has moisture sensors to invalidate warranty may be triggered. by changing colour on test coupons scattered near board and battery on iMac, iPad and maybe iPhone.

Also beware Apple and others use "no clean flux" which is corrosive with moisture and air so forced air drying is critical for long periods to get under chips with exposed solder/copper interface.

A nylon tooth brush is Ok for me with any finger  on ground plane (to bleed any possible static build up) and speeds up the process. I also use a central vac, but I don't recommend if you are not sure about flammability, but I use a bottle of ISOPROPYL alcohal instead which has high water content and needs vacuum assist with forced room air drying.  This has recovered several keyboards and laptops dead from spilt fluids including beer.  Just make sure rust hasn't started from moisture ingress (rain) from the no-clean flux (oximoron) and get it cleaned quickly.

This anti-oxidant is a excellent for RF contacts , USB and power contacts.

some LCD's use antiglare surface prep which can be dissolved but iPads do not with gorilla glass. – Tony Stewart